# Vimeo search API with Java and Scribe

Tags: java, search, oauth, vimeo, scribe

In its API Vimeo engineers are claiming that we should be able to search without access token, I have spent hours and unfortunately cannot get it to work, I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, So please help if you have done this before.

```
OAuthService service = new     ServiceBuilder().provider(VimeoApi.class).apiKey(consumerString).apiSecret(consumerSecret).build();

OAuthRequest myrequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2format=json&method=vimeo.videos.search&query=fun");

Token mytoken = new Token("", consumerSecret);
service.signRequest(mytoken, myrequest); 
Response response = myrequest.send();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this:

```
Token mytoken = new Token("", consumerSecret);
```

for this:

```
Token mytoken = new Token("", "");
```

Comment: fantastic Pablo, that worked! thank you very much for creating scribe - great work!

Comment: I am using client id as api key and client secret as apisecret.....but getting below mentioned response: {"generated_in":"0.0050","stat":"fail","err":{"code":"401","expl":"The oauth_signature passed was not valid.","msg":"Invalid signature"}}