# Vimeo Advanced API: Searching for public videos in JAVA with SCRIBE

Tags: java, search, oauth, vimeo, scribe

I'm trying to search for videos on VIMEO using their advanced API, in order to get some basic info about them such as their video ID and Thumbnail URL.

This is my code, which I pretty much copied from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897492/vimeo-search-api-with-java-and-scribe?rq=1):

```
public void getResponse() {

    String consumerString = "consumer_key_from_vimeo_app";
    String consumerSecret = "consumer_secret_from_vimeo_app";

    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(VimeoApi.class)
            .apiKey(consumerString)
            .apiSecret(consumerSecret)
            .build();

    OAuthRequest  myrequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,
            "http://vimeo.com/api/rest/?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.search&page=1&per_page=3&summary_response=1&query=shakira");
    Token mytoken = new Token("", "");
    service.signRequest(mytoken, myrequest);
    Response response = myrequest.send();

    System.out.println(response.getBody());
}
```

I expect it to print a **JSON**. However, this prints the code for a "Not found" HTML page. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper Vimeo Advanced API url is "http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?method=METHOD". It looks like you are missing the v2. You can read more here : https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced#endpoint

Comment: I was using an older version of the API. Thanks for the help and sorry for the late reply!

Comment: @Dashron Hello there, would you have some time to look at my question regarding HTML-doc error from node.js vimeo-api that occured recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954095/vimeo-api-for-node-js-html-error-sorry-vimeo-will-be-right-back