# Vimeo-API for node.js HTML error 'Sorry. Vimeo will be right back'

Tags: html, node.js, error-handling, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using `Vimeo api` for `node.js` and now encountered a problem, that never occured before. On attempt to `lib.generateClientCredentials` it throws error (and crashes node app):

```
    [Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="nofollow, noindex">
  <title>Sorry. Vimeo will be right back.</title>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #34454E url('https://f.vimeocdn.com/images_v6/ins_down_illustr
ation.png') bottom repeat-x fixed;
      color: #ffffff;
      font: 36px/1.3 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #content {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      top: 35px;
      left: 0;
    }

    h1 {
      margin-bottom: 35px;
      height: 101px;
      background: url('https://f.vimeocdn.com/images_v6/ins_down_vimeo.png') cen
ter no-repeat;
      text-indent: -1000em;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    h2 {
      color: #717D83;
      font-size: 37px;
      font-weight: normal;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    p {
      margin: 0;
    }

    @media all and (min-height: 960px) {
      #content {
        top: 5%;
      }
    }

    @media all and (min-height: 1200px) {
      #content {
        top: 10%;
      }
    }

    @media all and (max-height: 900px) {
      body {
        background-position: center 300px;
      }

      #content {
        top: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Vimeo</h1>
    <h2>Something is weird in the magical forest.</h2>
    <p>We&rsquo;ll be back in a jiffy.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>]
```

So:
 1. Why is it happening?
 2. Why HTML being thrown as error in server side api? (to pass it to users I assume?)

**Edit:**
My `Vimeo-API` configuring module (Basicly the same as example in `Vimeo` docs):

```
var Vimeo = require('vimeo-api').Vimeo;

var lib = new Vimeo('*somethingsecret*', '*anothersecretthing*');
lib.generateClientCredentials('public', function (err, access_token) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    var token = access_token.access_token;
    lib.access_token = token;
    // Other useful information is included alongside the access token
    // We include the final scopes granted to the token. This is important because the user (or api) might revoke scopes during the authentication process
    var scopes = access_token.scope;
});

module.exports = lib;
```

**Edit2:** After installing `vimeo 0.1.4 module` first server startup was succesfull, vimeo api was working fine, but after restart, on any api request, I am recieving

`error: A valid user token must be passed`.

Sometimes it works after server reload, sometimes it starts throwing this errors.

Comment: Has it been solved yet? I'm having the same issues, some people else as well, see: https://vimeo.com/forums/api/topic:265764

Comment: nope, it magicly self repaired iteslf yesterday, but from todays morning i see the same error. Weird enough it never occured for past 5 month of using vimeo-api, maybe it's somehow affected by modules that i installed yesterday, bu they are seems to be completely irrelevant (UglifyCSS and Forever-monitor), maybe my `npm install` also updated vimeo-api module, which i did not noticed, and this update screwed everything.

Comment: I believe it's a problem on vimeo's side and I hope their support respond as soon as possible. Vimeo-api hasn't been updated since two months or so (v.1.1.2) and doesn't rely on any thirdparty packages. I've also inspected the called requests and compared them to the current api documentation – all is well. :(

Comment: We're in the process of investigating this issue. It looks like in most cases the requests were unsuccessful to being with (incorrect client id/secret, missing access token, incorrect permissions), and the response is being overriden with this incorrect error message and response. If you contact support at vimeo.com/help/contact we can help you track down the root cause of the error.

Answer (score 3):

This is a temporary server side error. Vimeo has pushed an update to the official node.js library that should bypass the problem while we work on resolving the issue.

Make sure you are using the package `vimeo`, NOT `vimeo-api` and you are on version `1.1.3`

Comment: huh, I am on `vimeo-api`...  thx for some certainty, i will test new version a bit later.

Comment: vimeo-api is still the official library but will not be receiving updates past 1.1.2

Comment: installed `vemeo 1.1.4`, so far works as expected. Thank you.
Small unrelated question. It seems that i can't find info on how to supply multiple filters. I am trying to add content filter to request for related videos which already have 'related' filter. I was trying `query: {filter: 'related,content_rating'}` and `'related,content_rating'`  but it gives me 'invalid filter parameters'

Comment: Misspelled "and `'related content_rating'`".      

Also my happiness wasn't too long, sometimes on server reload api start throwing `error: A valid user token must be passed` on requests (added edit2 to my question)

Comment: Currently we do not support multiple filters. We are including that in  the upcoming 3.4 version. As for the token error, contact us directly at vimeo.com/help/contact with the token, and a full request log (we recommend runscope for generating logs) and we can help identify the problem.

Comment: i did not saw this problem in last few days, if i will catch it again, will dig deeper and contact support, thank You.

Answer (score 2):

As already said in the comments, I have experienced the same issues when requesting upload tickets. I think the problem lies in the vimeo.js node-api not sending Content-Length headers when doing post requests.

I have a fork of the repo here (https://github.com/johnnycrab/vimeo.js), where I am adding the Content-Length header, resolving all my issues for now. The method I am changing is `Vimeo.prototype.request` in the vimeo.js file, if you want to avoid my other changes.

Comment: We are working on fixing this server side. For more updates check out this issue: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js/issues/23

Comment: Thank you, i will checkout latest `vimeo` module, if still bugged will try Your fork.